# Manipulate Image controls in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I'm learning WPF in free time using Flickr.NET API.

The first feature I want to perform is search images by name/description/tags. This leads me to play around with Images in WPF.

This is my setup:

**- XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="PhotoList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="639" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1060" Style="{DynamicResource ScrollableItemControlStyle}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="639" Width="1060"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
                <Image Width="200" Source="{Binding Url}" Margin="0,0,5,5" MouseDown="OpenSelectedImage" MouseEnter="Image_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Image_MouseLeave">
                </Image>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <Button x:Name="BackButton" Style="{DynamicResource ModernButtonStyle}" Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="710,654,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="360" Height="56  " TabIndex="2" Background="#FF6600CC" IsDefault="True" Foreground="White" Click="BackButton_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

**- C#**

```
public ObservableCollection<PhotoResult> images;
public ImageSearchResult(List<PhotoResult> imageList)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if (imageList.Count > 0)
    {
        images = new ObservableCollection<PhotoResult>();
        foreach (var image in imageList)
        {
            images.Add(image);
        }
        PhotoList.ItemsSource = images;
    }
}
```

Could we achive:

1. My WrapPanel doesn't scroll at all.
2. When a mouse hover an Image control, I can have their size changed (with animation) to indicate selection. But it overlays other control, not rearrange position. Could we solve this one? I think ZIndex doesn't work as expected in this case.
3. Also, can we change the image border at selection? I'm not able to do it at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have some "Selection-Behaviour" you should use some WPF Control implementing ItemsControl - your "ItemsControl" does not provide any selection.

If you use a "Listbox" [(MSDN ListBox)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx) you can set your ItemsPanel to whatever you want. E.g. you could use a "UniformGrid" where each item shares the same size. You could set the desired rows/columns.

```
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate">
        <UniformGrid Rows="2"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

To achieve your resizing "MouseOver" or to set the Border in the selection case, you could define an "ItemContainerStyle" for the ListBox.

```
        <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1.25"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1.25"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFB61F1F"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Image x:Name="image" Height="100" Width="100">
                            <Image.LayoutTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Image.LayoutTransform>
                        </Image>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

In summary you can now use your ListBox combining the ItemsPanel and ItemContainerStyle in this way:

```
<ListBox ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ItemsPanelTemplate}" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
         ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle}" />
```

This is probably not the complete solution for all your questions, but it should provide a good starting point.

Comment: Sounds great. I will try it next time going back to the project.